# How to extract all pixel values in a raster file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, layers, pixel, frequency

I have a image difference from ArcGIS, which i have performed a remap function on.
The layer is a temporary layer and does not have an attribute table, i need all the pixel values to do a frequency distribution on but cannot find a way to do it. Pixel inspector doesn't give me a large enough area to cover the entire layer.

It seems like a really simple thing to do but I can't figure it out. Basically just get all the data from the raster, there is only 2 values, 1 and 2. I just need to know how many times each one appears

Comment: Is there a problem to build the  raster attribute table ?

Comment: What format are your raster data in?

Comment: What data type is your raster (pixel type/depth)?

Comment: Please do not re-ask the same question.  There is advice here about what to do if you want to draw attention to the original: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/what-should-i-do-if-my-question-was-asked-but-there-is-no-accepted-answer-for-t

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Arc user, but the function you're interested is a statistics calculator for your raster file. Depending on the output you need, you could either use an ArcMap/Catalog tool to view a histogram of your raster data, or you could perform some functions to export several statistical fields determined from your raster.

The ArcGIS website has several guides on calculating or exporting your raster statistics, like this page:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/calculating-statistics-using-geoprocessing-tools.htm